# Using MethodArgumentNotValidException for a comparison in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exceptionhandler

I have the following comparison between 2 fields and if the comparison result is less than zero, I need to throw exception with a message like `"Amount cannot be less than balance"`.

I think `MethodArgumentNotValidException` is a proper type for this scenario. However, `MethodArgumentNotValidException` does not take a message parameter:

```
public void transfer(Request request) {

    if(sender.getBalance().compareTo(account.getAmount()) < 0)
        throw new MethodArgumentNotValidException(MESSAGE);

    // ...
}
```

So, should I implement a custom error class as shown below? I have also a Global Exception Handler class and this kind of custom classes for `"Element Not found"` or `"Element already exists"`.

```
public class CustomMethodArgumentNotValidException extends RuntimeException {

    public MethodArgumentNotValidException() {
        super();
    }

    public NoSuchElementFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

And then use add this custom exception to my Global Exception Handler? Or should I directly use it without any custom implementation as extra?

**Update:**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                  HttpHeaders headers,
                                                                  HttpStatusCode statusCode,
                                                                  WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY.value(), VALIDATION_ERROR);
        for (FieldError fieldError : ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
            errorResponse.addValidationError(fieldError.getField(), fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body(errorResponse);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchElementFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoSuchElementFoundException(NoSuchElementFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return buildErrorResponse(ex, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(InsufficientFundsException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentInvalidException(InsufficientFundsException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return buildErrorResponse(ex, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(AuthenticationException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAuthenticationException(AuthenticationException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return buildErrorResponse(ex, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, request);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllUncaughtException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        return buildErrorResponse(ex, UNKNOWN_ERROR, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> buildErrorResponse(Exception ex,
                                                      HttpStatusCode statusCode,
                                                      WebRequest request) {
        return buildErrorResponse(ex, ex.getMessage(), statusCode, request);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> buildErrorResponse(Exception ex,
                                                      String message,
                                                      HttpStatusCode statusCode,
                                                      WebRequest request) {
        final ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(statusCode.value(), message);
        if (printStackTrace && isTraceOn(request)) {
            errorResponse.setStackTrace(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(statusCode).body(errorResponse);
    }

    private boolean isTraceOn(WebRequest request) {
        String[] value = request.getParameterValues(TRACE); // TRACE from app properties
        return Objects.nonNull(value)
                && value.length > 0
                && value[0].contentEquals("true");
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(
            Exception ex,
            Object body,
            HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpStatusCode statusCode,
            WebRequest request) {

        return buildErrorResponse(ex, statusCode, request);
    }
}
```

```
public class InsufficientFundsException extends RuntimeException {

    public InsufficientFundsException() {
        super();
    }

    public InsufficientFundsException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public InsufficientFundsException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the Spring provided [`MethodArgumentNotValidException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/MethodArgumentNotValidException.html). It is in the `org.springframework.web.bind` package, this will bind your code to Spring and it binds it to web related classes.

So unless you don't mind binding to Spring and your class is only used in web related classes you could opt for its usage.

However you are probably better of using an exception of your own which would convey what is wrong, like an `InsufficientFundsException` or reuse the general purpose `IllegalArgumentException`. But throwning stronger typed exceptions is probably the better way.